# How can I view a Django created model (document in mongodb) in mogodb console?

Tags: django, mongodb

I am trying to put a documnet in mongodb. I can do it easily. But how can I view than document through mymongodb console?

Comment: do you mean MongoShell ? on mongo shell you have `show dbs` and `show collections` commands, use `db."yourCollectionName".find()` to see all the records from your collection.

Comment: Being someone who never used Mongo with Django, is it implemented as the SQL backends? For them, there is a `manage.py` command called `dbshell`, which opens an SQL client. Maybe it works with Mongo, too, but that’s just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

They have pretty good documentation here on how to use the Mongodb shell.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/

If you're using Mongolabs, just login and go to documents under your database section.

Comment: No i tried it actually.Iam able to create  document through mongodb and able to view it. But i can't  view a mongodb documnet that was created  through Django MVC .